# update several rows using inner join in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-update, inner-join

i have this stored procedure:

```
 create procedure jk_insertSPUSH
 @regID int,
 @favDT favoriteID readonly
 as
 begin
  select * into #_tmp_fav_table from @favDT

alter table #_tmp_fav_table
add handsetID varchar(max)

update #_tmp_fav_table set handsetID=(select handset_type_id
                                      from registration r
                                      INNER JOIN buddies b ON b.reg_id=@regID 
                                      INNER JOIN @favDT f ON  b.favorite_id=f.favorite_id
                                       where r.reg_id=f.favorite_id)
    end
```

i need to update the column that i added to the temp table `#_tmp_fav_table` but my select returns several values... and i need to update all the rows of the table with all the `handset_type_id` that are returned according to the `f.favorite_id` so i need to do the update as many times as i have `f.favorite_id`

i hope i made my problem clear...

Comment: You want to store all handset_type_id's in column handsetID? I.e. with comma separation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but something like this might help you:

```
   UPDATE t
    SET handsetId = r.handset_type_id
    FROM #_tmp_fav_table t
    INNER JOIN registration r ON r.favorite_id=t.favorite_id
    INNER JOIN buddies b ON b.reg_id=@regID 
    INNER JOIN @favDT f ON  b.favorite_id=f.favorite_id
    where r.reg_id=f.favorite_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use UPDATE FROM statement:

```
UPDATE
    #_tmp_fav_table 
SET
    handsetID = handset_type_id
FROM
    #_tmp_fav_table FT
    INNER JOIN @favDT F ON  ...
    INNER JOIN registration r ON r.reg_id=f.favorite_id
    INNER JOIN buddies b ON ...
```